# Cant install esri arcgis thorugh conda on macos (m1)

Tags: python, conda, arcgis

I keep getting this problem when I try and install arcgis. I'm using the line:

`conda install -c esri arcgis`

and the output is this:

```bash
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Collecting package metadata (repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
PackagesNotFoundError: The following packages are not available from current
channels:
- arcgis
Current channels:
https://conda.anaconda.org/Esri/osx-arm64
https://conda.anaconda.org/Esri/noarch
https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/osx-arm64
- https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
To search for alternate channels that may provide the conda package you're looking for, navigate to

https://anaconda.org

and use the search bar at the top of the page
```

How can I install arcgis into my conda env without getting this error? thank you

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I am using an M1 Mac as well. Apparently they have not written it for osx64 yet. You could try running it in a virtual machine. https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/get-started/run-pro-on-a-mac.htm

https://doesitarm.com/app/arcgis-cityengine

If you can, you should check out qgis, there is a version that works on apple silicon available but I’m not sure if it’s good enough for what you have in mind.

https://doesitarm.com/app/qgis/

Comment: Its important to note that the arcgis library is to interact with arcgis online it is not a general purpose GIS library. QGIS is not a good alternative here.